# Do i just need to run `nuxt generate` without setting `target: static` to build an SSG in Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In the [Official Guide](http://localhost:3000/) it says that If to generate a static site, there are two ways:

- Prerendering (Which is to my understanding is **SSG**: By running `nuxt generate`.
- Client-Only Rendering (SPA): By setting `ssr: false` and running `nuxt generate`.

So is `nuxt generate` a shortcut and it just sets `target` to `static` so that I don't have to do it manually in the `nuxt.config`? I tried using the command with and without setting `target: static` and it produced the same output but not sure if there are any caveats.

[image: Nuxt Official Docs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, there is no specific reason of having an `SPA` with a Node.js server, so `nuxt build` is irrelevant in this case.
Having as SSG or SSR depending on the script that you use seems logical indeed.

Before, we need to have:

- `ssr: true` and `target: 'server'` then run `nuxt build`
- `ssr: true` and `target: 'static'` then run `nuxt generate`

It looks more logic to only have the launched script by `nuxt` deciding that and this is what the team apparently took as a final approach.

So no, I don't think that there are any kind of drawbacks to that. It's mainly a better/faster DX.

PS: if you put `target: 'server'` but use `nuxt generate`, you still have the whole thing generated for a `static` deploy.

Comment: It's much better for DX now indeed. I wish the docs had more details like this.